# Sequência de Fibonacci

Tags: java, algoritmo, matemática

Preciso fazer um exercício sobre a sequência de Fibonacci:

> Cada novo termos na sequência de Fibonacci é gerada a partir da soma
>   dos 2 termos anteriores. Se começarmos com 1 e 2, os primeiros dez
>   números serão: 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... Considerando os
>   termos da sequência de Fibonacci com valores menores que cem mil,
>   encontre a soma de todos os números pares. Resposta: 60696

e estou quase chegando lá, vejam o código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int termo1 = 1;
        int termo2 = 2;
        int termos[] = new int[10];
        int soma = 0;
        termos[0] = 1;
        termos[1] = 2;

        for (int i = 2; i < termos.length; i++) {
            termos[i] =  termos[i - 1] + termos[i - 2];
        }

        for (int termo : termos ) {
            if (termo % 2 == 0) {
                soma += (long) termo;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(soma);


    }
```

Estou usando *arrays*, e estou conseguindo fazer com os 10 primeiros termos da sequência, o problema é que quando troco o tamanho do *array* para 100000, a soma dos termos dá errado, e número negativo, como se a variável soma não suporta-se.

Comment: Tenta fazer "`int soma = 0;`" ser "`long soma = 0;`"

Comment: Eu fiz, deu -289570595282

Comment: Eu troquei os int pra long e deu "7203226363417812526" ao fazer a matriz assim "`long termos[] = new long[100000];`"; deveria ter dado "60696"?

Comment: Sim, se você analisar o algorítimo, estou fazendo a soma de todos os termos pares, então só precisaria mudar o tipo das variáveis pra dar 60696

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O algoritmo não faz o que está no enunciado. Ele não pede para criar *array*. Ok, é uma forma, mas confusa e não otimizada. Ele manda parar quando a soma chegar em 100000, isso nunca é verificado. Ele não fala quantas interações precisam se feitas.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int termo1 = 1;
        int termo2 = 2;
        int soma = 0;
        while (termo2 < 100000) {
            int novoTermo = termo1 + termo2;
            if (novoTermo % 2 == 0) soma += novoTermo;
            termo1 = termo2;
            termo2 = novoTermo;
        }
        System.out.println(soma);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/oIBLz2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fyngnmbd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Math/Fibonacci.cs).

Comment: `class HelloWorld`...

Comment: C# já é uma desgraça pq exige classe até em coisa simples, Java é pior por exigir o mesmo nome do arquivo, aí dá muito trabalho trocar nesses IDE online.